# Importing a JSON file to a SQL Server database using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, json, vb.net

I want to import a big JSON file with this structure:

```
{
  "series_id":"NG.RL2R04SOK_1.A",
  "name":"Oklahoma Natural Gas Plant Liquids, Reserves Revision Decreases, Annual",
  "units":"Million Barrels",
  "f":"A",
  "unitsshort":"MMbbl",
  "description":"Oklahoma Natural Gas Plant Liquids, Reserves Revision Decreases",
  "copyright":"None","source":"EIA, U.S. Energy Information Administration",
  "iso3166":"USA-OK",
  "start":"1979",
  "end":"2008",
  "last_updated":"13-AUG-13 11.49.51 AM",
  "data":[
     ["2008","136"],
     ["2007","73"],
     ... 
     ["1980","69"],
     ["1979","54"]
  ]
}
```

into a SQL Server database.

Usually I use VB.net to import CSV/TXT/Excel into this database, but I have no knowledge of JSON.

Is there a simple way to do that ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to save the json string/file save it.  Are you really asking how to deserialize the json to data so you can import/save various data elements?

Comment: From your description it sounds like you are trying to do this in sql server directly, without vb.net. Is that the case?

Comment: No, there isn't a simply way to do that

Comment: You will have to do that on SSIS and code it. I would personally recommend C# and not VB but that is your choice. You will need to create an object that has the same structure as the JSON and use a json deserializer on the code to put it into the object. Then you will need to load the object into the database. On the other hand though, SQL Server 2016 is compatible with JSON and has some built in functionality.

Comment: Thanks for all replies, but unfortunately, I don't have direct access to the SQL server (and its SQL Server 2012).
That's why I just need a Json parser to convert into a, for example, a datatable object, wich i could easily inject into my database.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016 you can open (and import) json files directly using TSQL:

```
SELECT import.*
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'f:\import.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
WITH( 
    [series_id]    nvarchar(100), 
    [name]         nvarchar(100),
    [units]        nvarchar(100),
    [f]            nvarchar(100),
    [unitsshort]   nvarchar(100),
    [description]  nvarchar(100),
    [copyright]    nvarchar(100),
    [iso3166]      nvarchar(100),
    [start]        int,
    [end]          int,
    [last_updated] nvarchar(100),
    [data]         nvarchar(100) 
) AS import
```

This query returns a table containing data read from json file and organized with the columns specified in the `WITH` clause.